# Hide a button if variable is below a certain amount

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to hide a button if a criteria is not met. As soon as the criteria is met, I would like the button to be visible.

I have tried various things, and the last thing I tried was:

```html
<button id="Stuff">Stuff Button</button>

<script>
  if (data.things >= 10) {
    document.getElementById("Stuff").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Stuff").disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

With the above, the button is always greyed out and never becomes clickable.

Firstly, am I doing something obviously wrong and secondly, is there a better way to go about this?

Many thanks

L Nomran

Comment: Where does `data.things` come from?

Comment: Based on the code you've posted, it looks like it only runs one time and data.things is >= 10 when it runs. Does anything change the value and re-evaluate the condition?

Comment: Did you mean you wanted the button to disappear or just be disabled? You can set visibility to `hidden`

Comment: Please edit the snippet I've added to create a working demo. Just mock up the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that there is working code for checking when `data.things` changes, and not just the code you posted. Just add the following CSS code, selecting the button `#Stuff` when it's disabled.

Also, you don't need an if statement.

```
#Stuff[disabled] {
  display: none;
}

<button id="Stuff">Stuff Button</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("Stuff").disabled = data.things < 10;
</script>
```